# Memory profiling a .NET 3.5 running process

Tags: .net, performance, memory, memory-leaks, profiling

Is there a tool for attaching to a *running* process which is in **.NET 3.5** and take a snapshot?

I have looked at [.NET Memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/download.aspx), [dotTrace memory](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/download_thanks.jsp?os=64) and [RedGate ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=CJu10LyD-bICFYTMtAodq0UA7Q) and none of them seems to be able to do it.

.NET Memory profiler and ANTS can attach to only to .NET 4.0 processes and dotTrace memory does not seem to be able to attach to running processes.

---

## UPDATE

OS is Windows Server 2003 (R2).

Comment: If you are running in Windows Vista or higher you can use Task Manager to take a dump of the process. then you can load this dump file into .NET Memory Profiler (I do it all the time....)

Comment: @Asher does it work with .NET 3.5?? If so add the answer please. Operating system is Windows server 2003.

Comment: Yes it will. In Windows Server 2003 the built in Windows Task Manager doesn't have the option to create a dump for a process but you can use Process Explorer to do that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question, ANTS can use with .NET 4.0 or higher. What you have to do is [forcing your application to use .NET 4](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/AMP8/Forcing+your+application+to+use+.NET+4), this does not required you to recompile the code. It just forced the application to use .NET 4 runtime.

Comment: -1. You need to read the question. A process *running* .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Aliostad I guess you meant that the process COMPILED with .NET 3.5 compiler which obviously can run under .NET 4.0 runtime. As far as I know, .NET 4.0 Runtime or higher can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The memory profiler in [Telerik JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx) will take snapshots of 2.0/3.5 applications. You may receive a warning that it won't attach the profiler, but if you do it anyway JustTrace will attach a debugger to get the same info. *Note: this only works for the memory profiler, not the performance profiler.*